# Using exclamation point in sed command on bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a file such as this, which I am wanting to manipulate with `sed`.

```
// file.js
return foo.quux();
```

Running the following:

```
$ sed -i "s/foo\.(?!bar|baz)/qux\./g" file.js
```

Expected the file to be replaced such as:

```
// file.js
return qux.quux();
```

But `bash` keeps telling me:

```
bash: !bar: event not found
```

Rewrote as:

```
$ sed -i "s/foo\.(?'!'bar|baz)/qux\./g" file.js
```

But `bash` still wants to use the exclamation point for it's own purposes:

```
bash: !: event not found
```

Anyone have any tips on how to craft the exclusion for `sed` without `bash` trying to get involved?

Comment: That's history expansion messing you up -- it's an interactive feature not relevant for scripting (turned off during script execution). You can turn it off in your interactive shell too. Note that questions about *interactive* shell use, vs script development, are often a better fit for [unix.se] than StackOverflow.

Comment: Cool. This is starting to turn into enough commands it should be in a script anyway, so this question of mine is becoming irrelevant.